# Control of styling text in the table and td tags

Tags: html-table, tags

I have a table that is responsive too
But when I increase the text in the td tag, table style changes
how can I do this issue? I mean which class of Bootstrap is for this issue and control of this changing

```
  <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-12 py-6">
                <div class="card card-profile card-secondary"   >
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-image: url(assets/img/blogpost.jpg)">

                        <div class="profile-picture center-align">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-xl">
                                <img src="assets/img/profile.jpg" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body  ">
                        <div class="user-profile text-center">
                            <div class="desc">Ege</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer" >
                        <div class="row user-stats text-center">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class=" ">125  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i></div>
                          
                            
                                
                                <div class=" ">Score</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class=" ">25</div>
                                <div class=" accordion-danger">Sell</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">

                                <div class=" ">134</div>
                                <div class="">Meal</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```